# C++ - How to fully wrap a subprocess

Tags: c++, fork, popen, dup

My goal is to:

Pipe stdin to stdin of child process.

Pipe stdout of child process to stdout.

Pipe stderr of chile process to stderr.

I have looked at these:

http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/popenRWE

and

http://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/how-to-capture-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-of-child-program/

but am having trouble doing what I listed.

Comment: Which of those three have you gotten to work, and which are you having trouble with?

Comment: If you want to connect the child process's stdin/stdout/stderr to your stdin/stdout/stderr you don't have to do anything, it inherits them automatically.

Comment: @Bamar I keep learning the same two things: 1) I make things more complicated than they need to be.  2) People on SO are very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bamar, if you want to make that into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Barmar if you want to make that into an answer, I will accept it. (sorry for the typo in your name/handle before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect the child process's stdin/stdout/stderr to your stdin/stdout/stderr you don't have to do anything, it inherits them automatically.

Note that this doesn't give your application any access to the data -- it just goes directly between the child process application and the original streams. So it's not really "wrapping" anything.